# Proper way to initialize a custom UIView programmatically with custom data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a `UIViewController` called `DogViewController.h/.m`. I am creating a custom `UIView` called `DogBoneView.h/.m` that currently looks like this:

**DogBoneView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DogBoneView : UIView
@end
```

**DogBoneView.m**

```
#import "DogBoneView.h"

@interface DogBoneView ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *dogMessageLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *dogDateLabel;
@end

@implementation DogBoneView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

        // Create labels
        self.dogMessageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, 30)];
        self.dogDateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, frame.size.width, 30)];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Then in `DogViewController.m` I create an instance of `DogBoneView` like this:

```
DogBoneView *dbv = [[DogBoneView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,60];
```

**My Question:**

How can I pass an `NSString` and `NSDate` into my `DogBoneView` instance? Should I create setters in `DogBoneView` and call those in `DogViewController` after I initialize the instance? Should I create some kind of new `init` method in `DogBoneView`? Should I make the labels `dogMessageLabel` and `dogDateLabel` public properties of `DogBoneView`? What is best practice here?

Comment: It depends. Can the owner of the DogBoneView change "at will" the labels? I'd go for a initWithFrame:withDate:andMessage:` kind of init.

Answer (score 1):

If it is your intent that the `NSString` and `NSDate` *must* be set (i.e, it would be a programming error to leave either one unset), then specify an initializer which takes them as arguments, and mark the inherited `initWithFrame` as unavailable to force using your initializer:

```
@interface DogBoneView: UIView
    - (nonnull instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame __unavailable;
    - (nonnull instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
                                  message:(nonnull NSString *)message
                                     date:(nonnull NSDate *)date NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

As `initWithCoder:` is also a designated initializer of the superclass, you should also override it or mark it, too, as unavailable.

On the other hand, if the string and date can be empty, then just provide the accessors. You could still provide this type of convenience initializer (remove the `NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER` in that case).